# Instantiating Unity prefabs in a for loop - please help me understand how this works

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

What this for loop means in context of unity 3d

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
        Transform o = (Transform)Instantiate(prefab);
        o.localPosition = nextPosition;
        nextPosition.x += o.localScale.x;
```

i m following this [Tutorial](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/runner/)

Comment: [I downvoted because this question does not show research effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: Could you add more information about what's unclear? What do you currently understand from it?

Comment: We have written two answer which explain how the for loop you provide in the question works. If that didn't help you solve your problem, can you tell us what exactly you DON'T understand?

Comment: Dammm i m just new here i already research alot and i m not able to find any good answer so i asked here .Why so many downvotes now i probably blocked from asking questions. come on guys .

Comment: As my previous comment stated, you don't provide enough information as to what's troubling you with this loop. I'm closing this question as unclear because of this. Writing good questions is hard, so please don't be discouraged by it and view it as an opportunity to improve your questions :) People here are eager to help, but you have to help them help you. The question can be reopened once it becomes clear.

Answer (score 2):

"The next step is spawning the initial row of cubes. We'll use a simple loop for that, instantiating new objects, setting their position, and advancing nextPosition by the width of the object so they form an unbroken line. " This for loop is used to spaw the cubes in your level.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
```

- this means : run the code in the brackets based on the number of objects.

First of all you create a Transform object called o; this is the instantiated prefab. Since our goal is to spawn cubes in an unbroken line, also considering that we are using unit cubes(which means width=height=depth) we have to write:

```
o.localPosition = nextPosition;
nextPosition.x += o.localScale.x;
```

We set the position of o to nextPosition and then we increase the x component of nextPosition by o.localScale.x(which in our case is the width of the unit cube)

Answer (score 1):

Loop over desirable number of objects

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
```

Create an instance of object, cast to "Transform" type and save to variable "o"

```
        Transform o = (Transform)Instantiate(prefab);
```

Set position of object "o" to position from "nextPosition"

```
        o.localPosition = nextPosition;
```

Update x parameter of "nextPosition" of instantiated object.

```
        nextPosition.x += o.localScale.x;
```

If 1st object is created at nextPosition.x = 10, and width of on object is o.localScale.x = 2, then the 2nd object will be created at 12, 3rd at 14 and etc. To sum it up, bunch of objects are created in line.